# How to get the data inside the XML

Tags: javascript

I have this response data from the server that I authenticate.

> ```
> <session session-guid="D39C1215-2F31-8641-E5T2-C7G35RT69127" user-id="34"> </session>
> ```

How can I get the value of session-guid and user-id and store them into 1 variable for each.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript in a modern browser you can use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

For example, assuming you only have one `session` tag:

```
var session = document.querySelectorAll("session")[0];
var session_guid = session.getAttribute("session-guid");
var user_id = session.getAttribute("user-id");

console.log("session-guid: " + session_guid);
console.log("user-id: " + user_id);
```

If you have more that one session tag you can use `forEach` on the results of `querySelectorAll()` to locate the one you want.  If you know that you're only going to have one session element you can use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.querySelectorAll()[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the values client side. For this method you will need to add any custom class to your  element like below:

Now write below lines of code inside  tag:

```
var $mySession = jQuery(document.getElementsByClassName("mySession"));
for (i = 0; i < $mySession.length; i++) {
var sessionguid = jQuery($mySession[i]).attr('session-guid');
var userid = jQuery($mySession[i]).attr('user-id');
console.log(sessionguid);
console.log(userid);
}
```

You can check the values of "sessionguid" and "userid" variable in your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do to get the required data from the XML.

```
    function getXMLData(xml) {
        var txt, xmlDoc;
        //get the responseXML
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        txt = "";
        //get all the session nodes
        var sessions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("session");//this returns a array of nodes
        for(var i =0;i<sessions.length;i++){
           //iterate over nodes and get the attributes
           txt += sessions[i].getAttribute("session-guid")+"<br />";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

this function accepts the response as a parameter. And then extracts out the sessions nodes and the required attribute. You can modify it according to your requirements.

Here is a [**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gTIuLbvkWCLufasLdEaM?p=preview) demo for the same